# How to type unknown exports that will be imported with named imports in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am making an NPM package that transforms `process.env` and exports the transformed env for convenient use.

The module:

```
const transformedEnv = transform(process.env)

module.exports = transformedEnv
```

Using it (in a Babel / TS codebase):

```
import { SOME_ENV_VAR } from 'transform-env'
```

My module works as expected but I would like to provide a TypeScript definition.

The problem is that I cannot know what properties the env will have, so I cannot use named exports, and I cannot find a way to type "unknown" exports. I currently get the following TS2305 error, which makes complete sense, since I do not export anything with named exports:

```
error TS2305: Module '"transform-env"' has no exported member 'SOME_ENV_VAR'.
```

Is there a way type those unknown named exports (something like using a `*` in the exports?).

And if not, is there a way to bypass this error on the package-side instead of using a `@ts-ignore` on the consumer module side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to bypass the type checking of my module entirely by adding an `index.d.ts` next to the `index.js` file of my package, containing:

```
declare module 'transform-env'
```

This is definitely not ideal, I'd rather have real type definitions, but at least consumer projects can use `import { SOME_ENV_VAR } from 'transform-env'` without TypeScript blocking the compilation.

Still looking for better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import * as anyName from 'transform-env'
```

Comment: Yes, I can use `*` or the default export (`import env from 'transform-env'` works), but I would like to provide a more convenient interface to import the property directly, so the user doesn't have to destructure it later with `const { SOME_ENV_VAR } = env`